# How to file Income tax return from Salary certificate of previous employer?

Tags: income-tax, india, income-tax-refund, electronic-filing

Consider my scenario:

I worked in Company A - where my salary was below taxable limit. (< 2.5 lakhs), thus my employer issues me a "Salary Certificate"  and no Form 16. I left this company in January.

Now I joined Company B and there is no TDS from Jan - March salary, but they have given me Form 16.

Now, how can I fill ITR online with salary certificate. Do I have to upload salary certificate online?

Answer (score 1):

> how can I fill ITR online with salary certificate

Ideally you should have declared your income and submitted your Salary Certificate of Company A to Company B on joining. They would have factored this and arrived at tax accordingly.

Even now, when you fill in ITR online, you have to add both the salaries from company A and company B as income under the head salaries. The system would show the total taxes and tax deducted and pending taxes. If there is any additional taxes to be paid, pay this and it would show up in Advance taxes. Submit the return.